# Calling C program from a PHP script using shell_exec()

Tags: php, c, hash, web-applications, cryptography

I am totally new to Web Development and currently, I am stuck while building a Login page.

I wrote a PHP script that gets the username and password when entered. The password is then sent as a parameter to a C program that I wrote, which just hashes the password(MD5). This is done using the following code:

```
$username = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['passwd'];

$hashvalue = shell_exec("md5.exe $password");
```

Now when I enter my password in the login form as **1234** I get an output of **f7d4cef3bfacebfc49d5574e7d9c1d6f**

But when I use **1234** as my input while I am running the C program separately I get a different output **81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055**. This is also the output that I should actually be getting. As I checked with various online MD5 hashing programs which gave the same output.

In the C program, I use `gets()` to get the input and `printf` to display the output. Also, I've used MySQL database(phpMyAdmin).

**The C program CODE:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef union uwb {
    unsigned w;
    unsigned char b[4];
} MD5union;

typedef unsigned DigestArray[4];

unsigned func0( unsigned abcd[] ){
    return ( abcd[1] & abcd[2]) | (~abcd[1] & abcd[3]);}

unsigned func1( unsigned abcd[] ){
    return ( abcd[3] & abcd[1]) | (~abcd[3] & abcd[2]);}

unsigned func2( unsigned abcd[] ){
    return  abcd[1] ^ abcd[2] ^ abcd[3];}

unsigned func3( unsigned abcd[] ){
    return abcd[2] ^ (abcd[1] |~ abcd[3]);}

typedef unsigned (*DgstFctn)(unsigned a[]);



unsigned *calctable( unsigned *k)
{
    double s, pwr;
    int i;

    pwr = pow( 2, 32);
    for (i=0; i<64; i++) {
        s = fabs(sin(1+i));
        k[i] = (unsigned)( s * pwr );
    }
    return k;
}


unsigned rol( unsigned r, short N )
{
    unsigned  mask1 = (1<<N) -1;
    return ((r>>(32-N)) & mask1) | ((r<<N) & ~mask1);
}

unsigned *md5( const char *msg, int mlen)
{
    /*Initialize Digest Array as A , B, C, D */
    static DigestArray h0 = { 0x67452301, 0xEFCDAB89, 0x98BADCFE, 0x10325476 };
    static DgstFctn ff[] = { &func0, &func1, &func2, &func3 };
    static short M[] = { 1, 5, 3, 7 };
    static short O[] = { 0, 1, 5, 0 };
    static short rot0[] = { 7,12,17,22};
    static short rot1[] = { 5, 9,14,20};
    static short rot2[] = { 4,11,16,23};
    static short rot3[] = { 6,10,15,21};
    static short *rots[] = {rot0, rot1, rot2, rot3 };
    static unsigned kspace[64];
    static unsigned *k;

    static DigestArray h;
    DigestArray abcd;
    DgstFctn fctn;
    short m, o, g;
    unsigned f;
    short *rotn;
    union {
        unsigned w[16];
        char     b[64];
    }mm;
    int os = 0;
    int grp, grps, q, p;
    unsigned char *msg2;

    if (k==NULL) k= calctable(kspace);

    for (q=0; q<4; q++) h[q] = h0[q];   // initialize

    {
        grps  = 1 + (mlen+8)/64;
        msg2 = malloc( 64*grps);
        memcpy( msg2, msg, mlen);
        msg2[mlen] = (unsigned char)0x80;
        q = mlen + 1;
        while (q < 64*grps){ msg2[q] = 0; q++ ; }
        {
            MD5union u;
            u.w = 8*mlen;
            q -= 8;
            memcpy(msg2+q, &u.w, 4 );
        }
    }

    for (grp=0; grp<grps; grp++)
    {
        memcpy( mm.b, msg2+os, 64);
        for(q=0;q<4;q++) abcd[q] = h[q];
        for (p = 0; p<4; p++) {
            fctn = ff[p];
            rotn = rots[p];
            m = M[p]; o= O[p];
            for (q=0; q<16; q++) {
                g = (m*q + o) % 16;
                f = abcd[1] + rol( abcd[0]+ fctn(abcd) + k[q+16*p] + mm.w[g], rotn[q%4]);

                abcd[0] = abcd[3];
                abcd[3] = abcd[2];
                abcd[2] = abcd[1];
                abcd[1] = f;
            }
        }
        for (p=0; p<4; p++)
            h[p] += abcd[p];
        os += 64;
    }
    return h;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int j,k;
    char msg[500];
    gets(msg);
    unsigned *d = md5(msg, strlen(msg));
    MD5union u;
    for (j=0;j<4; j++){
        u.w = d[j];
        for (k=0;k<4;k++) 
            printf("%02x",u.b[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've read about many inbuilt functions like bcrypt, scrypt etc. But this is just for practice purpose and hence wanted to use my own code.

Thank you

Comment: Using `gets` for passwords.. well I wish you were developing for some banking system and I knew which one.

Comment: Never pass user input into a shell command.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why isn't `gets` safe?

Comment: It is so unsafe that it was removed from the language. But you have other security holes as noted by @chris85. Currently your code is susceptible to arbitrary code execution attack using many different approaches.

Comment: Yep, my answer is relevant, thanks for your C code.  If you initialise your temp string called msg before you use gets, you should get consistent MD5 results.  Use memset(msg,0,500);

Comment: Eugene Sh - was gets removed from the language?  Woah...about time :)

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function such as MD5 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Within your C program, assuming it is MD5 hashing the input string correctly, then it might actually be OK.

The problem may not indeed be a problem at all, your MD5 hash can be correct from both processes.  (Even though they **look** entirely different, they can '*hold*' the same value `'1234'`) It is just that the stack has different content from one instance to another, and some of your string AFTER the null comes from the stack.

What is happening is that in one instance the C function is hashing this string
`'1234__________________'`  (where _ is the null or \0 char

and the other instance is hashing this string
`'1234_some_random_values'`.

Both strings contain `1234` following by the `null` character, but the characters AFTER the null are different.

Trying pre-filling your temporary string with all null values, then copy across your password, so that you are sure that the rest of the string buffer is 'empty' before you MD5 hash it.

(You can confirm this by unMD5 hashing if you like to verify I am correct.  From Wikipedia, you can see the hash algortihm takes 'blocks' of data and does not care where the NULL character is:

> MD5 processes a variable-length message into a fixed-length output of
>   128 bits. The input message is broken up into chunks of 512-bit blocks
>   (sixteen 32-bit words); the message is padded so that its length is
>   divisible by 512.

from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5
Also from this explanation if your password length was exactly (sixteen 32-bit words) 4 times 16 = 64 characters long, then the MD5 hash should be the same regardless of what follows in the character array after the null character, as the algorithm will not look for more characters after the 64 char boundary.
)

Try adding

```
memset(msg,0,500);
```

before your `gets`.

(I am disregarding all the security concerns :)  )

Comment: temporary string? can you please give an example?

Comment: You do not 'need' a temporary string within your function, but if you do use a temp string you will see what I mean a bit easier...  Copy password to Temp, MD5 the Temp string, return Temp string...Then you can play with the contents of the Temp string to ensure the characters after the null are controlled (ie the same all the time) before you implement MD5 on the Temp string

Comment: Add your C code to your question, then I will modify it for you - to show you how the chars on the end of the string (after null) will change your MD5 value...

Comment: Thank you @Grantly , I'll give it a try.

Comment: You're welcome, hope its not confusing.  Its a little tricky to grasp this 'problem' sometimes

Comment: Noted :)  See revised answer

Comment: Ok, now I am getting a different output, not the desired one though. :/

Comment: Is the output correct?  (I mean - have you verified any of your different outputs?)  I would wager that they are all correct and reverse MD5 back to 1234 (Assuming your MD5 is working properly)

Comment: Realise you are NOT MD5ing the string 1234.  You are MD5ing the string 1234 plus whatever happens to occupy the rest of the character array after the null value up to 64 chars

Comment: The MD5 is working properly when I run the C program separately. But every time I enter the password in the login form I am getting the **same** wrong output, no matter the password (i.e. the output isn't changing).

Comment: I don't know php that well, but shouldn't this line be $hashvalue = shell_exec("md5.exe " + $password);   ?  ie $password not in the quotes

Comment: You are probably always getting the MD5 hash for the string '$password'...:)

Comment: No, The syntax in its documentation shows shell("md5.exe $password"); ie the exe file and the parameter should be inside the same quotes.

Comment: $password is not a parameter.  Its a variable.  Its value is the parameter, but I know what you mean :)  Perhaps its correct, I'm a php novice

Comment: Just checked that, it isn't the case. The MD5 hash of '$password' is different from what I am getting.

Comment: Can you replicate your MD5 results on a 'known' platform?  ie on a MD5 generating website?  You probably have already....

Comment: Yea, I am getting the same result which I get when running the C program separately.

Comment: Have you tried this "add  '2>&1' to the end of your shell command to have STDERR returned as well as STDOUT.

$shell_return = shell_exec($shell_command." 2>&1");"  ... from http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Is your PHP mixing up 64bit code with a 32bit C program?

Comment: Can you process the args instead of using gets... You might be getting different characters in the gets call from the buffer in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a great point for you to do 2 things

1. start thinking about the security of your design
2. familiarize yourself with PHP standard lib, specifically

   http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

I listed security first because, well, as some others have pointed out, you shouldn't be accessing the GET or POST directly. Since you're just practicing, start programming with security always in your mind, don't reinvent the wheel and good luck to you.